# Preencher Combobox com Dapper

Tags: c#, winforms, dapper

Estou usando um componente de *combobox* com o *Dapper*, porém não estou conseguindo preencher a combobox corretamente, segue trecho do código:

```
LookUpEdit ctlControle = (LookUpEdit) pr_Controle;
var parametro = new DynamicParameters();
parametro.Add("@TABELA_NOME", pr_TabelaNome);
parametro.Add("@TABELA_CAMPO_VALOR", pr_CampoValor);
parametro.Add("@TABELA_CAMPO_DISPLAY", pr_CampoDisplay);

ctlControle.Properties.DataSource = acessoDados.criarConexao().Query("PRP_PREENCHER_COMBO", parametro, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
ctlControle.Properties.ValueMember = pr_CampoValor;
ctlControle.Properties.DisplayMember = pr_CampoDisplay;
ctlControle.Properties.PopulateColumns();
```

Então ao adicionar ao *datasource* ele preenche erroneamente colocando todos os campos na mesma linha do *Combobox* (*lookupedit* da *devexpress*). Como posso fazer isto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma coisa que o Dapper não esclarece é que o retorno dele não é exatamente estruturado do jeito que um *data source* de um componente .NET espera, então escrevi um método de extensão que converte o resultado pra algo mais inteligível, como uma lista, por exemplo:

```
public static class DapperExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> ToTypedList<T>(this IEnumerable<dynamic> list, bool colunasMaiusculas = true)
        where T: class, new()
    {
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

        foreach (var element in list)
        {
            var obj = new T();
            foreach (var keyValue in ((IDictionary<string, object>) element).Where(e => e.Value != null)) 
            {
                PropertyInfo property;
                if (colunasMaiusculas) 
                { 
                    property = properties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.ToUpper() == keyValue.Key);
                } else {
                    property = properties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == keyValue.Key);
                }

                switch (property.PropertyType.ToString())
                {
                    case "System.Int32":
                        property.SetValue(obj, Convert.ToInt32(keyValue.Value));

                        break;
                    case "System.Int64":
                        property.SetValue(obj, Convert.ToInt64(keyValue.Value));

                        break;
                    case "System.DateTime":
                        property.SetValue(obj, Convert.ToDateTime(keyValue.Value));

                        break;
                    default:
                        if (keyValue.Value != null)
                        {
                            property.SetValue(obj, keyValue.Value);
                        }

                        break;
                }
            }

            yield return obj;
        }
    }
}
```

Use assim:

```
ctlControle.Properties.DataSource = acessoDados.criarConexao().Query("PRP_PREENCHER_COMBO", parametro, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToTypedList<ClasseDeDados>().ToList();
```

`ClasseDeDados` é uma classe que possui os mesmos campos que vêm do banco.

Comment: é uma solução bastante interessante, não há como fazer isso sem colocar uma ClasseDeDados ? pois estou fazendo isso em uma função genérica e nao consegui uma forma de passar uma ClasseDeDados como parametro.

Comment: outra questão, vale a pensa usar o Dapper ou é melhor ficar no EF mesmo ?

Comment: Dá pra fazer com `ExpandoObject`, mas não tenho certeza se funciona. Sobre Dapper ou EF, depende do que você quer. Dapper dá um pouco mais de trabalho mas o desempenho fica animal. Já o EF resolve tudo pra você. Você só se preocupa com a regra de negócio do seu sistema, mas é obviamente mais lento.

Comment: entendi, obrigado pela ajuda, fico te devendo uma breja =]

Comment: [Não seja por isso](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=58B8G88A995VJ) ;)